# Comparing unique values from separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that are similar in terms of the data they show (areas, regions, etc), and I am interested in one particular variable, the `Area` variable.

For the 2 dataframes, namely `a` and `b` , I have checked what areas each have by using `a.Area.unique()` and `b.Area.unique()`, and also checked the number in each by using `nunique()`.

However, they do not have the same amount of variables, and I need to identify what areas are missing / additional from either dataframe. How can I check the 2 dataframes against each other to identify the difference?

I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcom to SO. Please do share sample data. It helps the community to help you and increases the probabiblity of someone choosing to help.

Comment: Might be useful to know that `a` has 151 unique areas, whilst `b` has 153. I need to find out these 2 extra areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could help better if you could update your question with some sample data, but one potential answer is using `merge` method:

```
new_df = pd.merge(a, b, on='Area', how='outer')
```

This new_df gives you a union of dataframe based on `Area` column between two dataframes.

Another solution could be:

```
a.loc[~a['Area'].isin(b['Area']), 'Area']
```

This gives you areas in `a` which are not in `b['Area'] series`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to set and use set operations for checking

```
a_set=set(a.Area.unique())
b_set=set(b.Area.unique())

list(a_set-b_set) # list of areas in a but not in b
list(b_set-a_set) # list of areas in b but not in a
list(b_set&a_set) # list of areas in both a and b >> intersection
list(b_set|a_set) # list of all areas >> union
```